# Could this PHP code be simplified or improved?

Tags: php, refactoring

I was wondering if the following code could be refactored/improved/simplified?  I'm posting this here, as I'd like another programmer's perspective/view; it's always good to see what others would do.

```
<?php

function moderateTopic($topic_id, $action = NULL) {
    $locked_query       = "SELECT topic_id FROM forum_topics WHERE status = 'locked' AND topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
    $locked_count       = totalResults($locked_query);
    $announcement_query = "SELECT topic_id FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_type = 2 AND topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
    $announcement_count = totalResults($announcement_query);
    $sticky_query        = "SELECT topic_id FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_type = 3 AND topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
    $sticky_count       = totalResults($sticky_query);

    if (is_null($action) == FALSE) {
        switch ($action) {
            case 1:
                if ($locked_count > 0) {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET status = 'unlocked' WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                } else {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET status = 'locked' WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                }
                doQuery($topic_query);
                break;
            case 2:
                if ($announcement_count > 0) {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 1 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                } else {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 2 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                }
                doQuery($topic_query);
                break;
            case 3:
                if ($sticky_count > 0) {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 1 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                } else {
                    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 3 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
                }
                doQuery($topic_query);
                break;
            case 4:
                header('Location: ' . urlify(9, $topic_id));
                break;
            case 5:
                header('Location: ' . urlify(11, $topic_id));
                break;
        }
        header('Location: ' . urlify(2, $topic_id));
    } else {
        $locked       = $locked_count > 0 ? 'Unlock' : 'Lock';
        $announcement = $announcement_count > 0 ? 'Unannounce' : 'Announce';
        $sticky       = $sticky_count > 0 ? 'Unsticky' : 'Sticky';

        return <<<EOT
<div style="float: right;">
<form method="POST">
<select name="action" onChange="document.forms[0].submit();">
<option value="">- - Moderate - -</option>
<option value="1"> =&gt; {$locked}</option>
<option value="2"> =&gt; {$announcement}</option>
<option value="3"> =&gt; {$sticky}</option>
<option value="4"> =&gt; Move</option>
<option value="5"> =&gt; Delete</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
EOT;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: http://refactormycode.com/ is a better bet for this sort of question.

Comment: @therefromhere this lame site you linked to cannot make any code better. worst, most likely

Comment: @Col. haha, I admit I've not used it.  But the Stackoverflow engine doesn't really lend itself to code refactoring.  Maybe there's a better alternative out there.

Comment: Make your first 3 queries into one `"SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = ".intval($topic_id)` and then reduce your branchy case to make it change only necessary variables. see this question for the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359642/php-making-cleaner-shorter-code/ Also don't return any HTML from this function, but an array of data and learn to use templates. That's all

Comment: @therefromhere in fact, no engine is needed. But brains and experience only.

Comment: @Newbtophp - The optimization checking is simple, **IF** only one row for `$topic_id`, you should combine three queries into one. **IF** multiple rows matching for `$topic_id` use `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by looking for duplication.  I see 6 very similar occurrences of a query string:

```
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET status = 'unlocked' WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET status = 'locked' WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 1 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 2 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 1 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
$topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET topic_type = 3 WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
```

Each of these is followed by an execution of the query.  So how about a method?

```
function setField($topic_id, $field, $value) {
    $topic_query = "UPDATE forum_topics SET '{$field}' = '{$value}' WHERE topic_id = '{$topic_id}'";
    doQuery($topic_query);
}
```

Now the first bit of your switch statement looks like this:

```
switch ($action) {
    case 1:
        if ($locked_count > 0) {
            setField($topic_id, 'status', 'unlocked');
        } else {
            setField($topic_id, 'status', 'locked');
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if ($announcement_count > 0) {
            setField($topic_id, 'topic_type', 1);
        } else {
            setField($topic_id, 'topic_type', 2);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if ($sticky_count > 0) {
            setField($topic_id, 'topic_type', 1);
        } else {
            setField($topic_id, 'topic_type', 3);
        }
        break;
```

But I see I've screwed that up - sometimes the field is a string, and sometimes an int - and the int cases are all topic_type.  So make it work like this:

```
switch ($action) {
    case 1:
        if ($locked_count > 0) {
            setField($topic_id, 'status', 'unlocked');
        } else {
            setField($topic_id, 'status', 'locked');
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if ($announcement_count > 0) {
            setTopicType($topic_id, 1);
        } else {
            setTopicType($topic_id, 2);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if ($sticky_count > 0) {
            setTopicType($topic_id, 1);
        } else {
            setTopicType($topic_id, 3);
        }
        break;
```

Carry on in that vein and you may find that soon you are much happier with the state of your code.