# Inserting a record

Tags: php

**UPDATE 1:**

I've never come across PRG before, does anyone have a link to some sample code in PHP showing this in action?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

What is better and why?

If I have a registration form, should I post back to the form itself to insert into the database, or should the data be posted to another page which inserts data into the database?

Comment: Post to self, validate, insert, redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter as you **ought** to do HTTP redirect after POST request anyway.

However, most common practice is to send to the same URL, as it's described in [/POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern

a concise example:

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data 
    // ...
    // and then redirect:
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
$tpl = 'form.tpl.php';
include 'main.tpl.php';
?>
```

where `form.tpl.php` is a *template* contains HTML form with PHP code to display form values out of the `$form` array

```
<? foreach ($err as $line): ?>
<div style="error"><?=$line?></div>
<? endforeach ?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$form['name']?>"><br>
  <textarea name="comments"><?=$form['comments']?></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

and `main.tpl.php` is a main site template as it's described here: [Using Template on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988627/using-template-on-php/3989380#3989380)

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 1:** in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual logic is this:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST) {

        ... validate the data ...

        if ($valid) {

            ... insert into database ...

            $id = mysql_last_insert_id();
            header('Location: /view.php?id=' . $id);
            exit;

        }

    }
?>

...

<form action="thispage.php">

    <input name="foo" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['foo']) ? htmlentities($_POST['foo']) : null; ?>">
    <?php if (... foo failed validation ...) : ?>
        <p class="error">Please enter a valid foo!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

This:

- persist the form data until it is valid
- outputs validation messages
- invokes a redirect/GET cycle to display the newly created record